# How do I change the options from a dropdownlist based on the selected value from another dropdownlist using ajax?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ajax to change the options from a dropdownlist with a change event after a user selects an option from a separate dropdownlist and it isn't changing the options at all. Here is my ajax code which seems to work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // if user changes paper type
        $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
            var modelData = {
                paperType: $("#paperTypeJList").val(),
                urgency: $("#urgencyJList").val(),
                numOfPages: $("#numOfPagesJList").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("changeDropDownValues", "Home")',
                type: "GET",
                data: {paperType:modelData.paperType},
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
    });
```

Here is the code for the method that I'm calling with the ajax code

```
public void changeDropDownValues(string paperType)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> urgencyList1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select the Urgency", Value = "", Selected = true });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "60 Days", Value = "60", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "30 Days", Value = "30", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "20 Days", Value = "20", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "10 Days", Value = "10", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "7 Days", Value = "7", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "5 Days", Value = "5", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "4 Days", Value = "4", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "72 Hours", Value = "72", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "48 Hours", Value = "48", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "24 Hours", Value = "24", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "12 Hours", Value = "12", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 Hours", Value = "6", Selected = false });
        urgencyList1.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "3 Hours", Value = "3", Selected = false });

        List<SelectListItem> urgencyList2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select the Urgency", Value = "", Selected = true });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "10 Days", Value = "10", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "7 Days", Value = "7", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "5 Days", Value = "5", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "4 Days", Value = "4", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "72 Hours", Value = "72", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "48 Hours", Value = "48", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "24 Hours", Value = "24", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "12 Hours", Value = "12", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 Hours", Value = "6", Selected = false });
        urgencyList2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "3 Hours", Value = "3", Selected = false });

        switch (paperType)
        {
            case "Dissertation":
                ViewBag.urgency = new SelectList(urgencyList1, "Value", "Text");
                break;
            case "Research Proposal":
                ViewBag.urgency = new SelectList(urgencyList1, "Value", "Text");
                break;
            default:
                ViewBag.urgency = new SelectList(urgencyList2, "Value", "Text");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **WebForms**,then you should use **Cascaded DropDownList** of Asp.net **AJAX Control Toolkit**:

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Here is a [**Tutorial**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32725/Using-CascadingDropDown-with-a-Database)

**Updated:**

if you are working in **asp.net mvc**, you can implement cascaded drop down list this way:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: That is what I need but do you know of a tutorial for asp.net mvc 4? I can't get their code to work because it is older

Comment: @FranklinJosephMoormann MVC doesn't really need the Ajax Control Toolkit anymore. Although the toolkit is useful, ASP.Net MVC has plenty of tools to natively implement AJAX-driven behavior. (Tip: ASP.Net MVC is a very important tag to put on your question. Without it, regular ASP.Net is usually assumed to be the case for your problem).

Comment: yes @Flater thats why i edited and provided for both webforms and mvc

Comment: I was replying to the original poster, to add that MVC handles all types of Ajax content well. And the importance of complete tagging :) Edited my previous comment for clarity.